# R - Modifying several interrelated columns with dynamic lag data simultaneously

Tags: r

I have a dataset that look like

```
C_ID I_ID Loan R1 Prot_id Collateral R2 maxRank
1     A    c  341  1      p1        506  1       3
2     A    c  341  1      p2        366  2       3
3     A    c  341  1      p3        263  3       3
4     A    a  689  2      p1        506  1       3
5     A    a  689  2      p2        366  2       3
6     A    a  689  2      p3        263  3       3
7     A    d  720  3      p1        506  1       3
8     A    d  720  3      p2        366  2       3
9     A    d  720  3      p3        263  3       3
10    A    b  334  4      p1        506  1       3
11    A    b  334  4      p2        366  2       3
12    A    b  334  4      p3        263  3       3
13    A    e  752  5      p1        506  1       3
14    A    e  752  5      p2        366  2       3
15    A    e  752  5      p3        263  3       3
16    B    h  193  1      p5        529  1       2
17    B    h  193  1      p4        414  2       2
18    B    g  494  2      p5        529  1       2
19    B    g  494  2      p4        414  2       2
20    B    f  227  3      p5        529  1       2
21    B    f  227  3      p4        414  2       2
22    B    j  785  4      p5        529  1       2
23    B    j  785  4      p4        414  2       2
24    B    i  371  5      p5        529  1       2
25    B    i  371  5      p4        414  2       2
26    B    k  395  6      p5        529  1       2
27    B    k  395  6      p4        414  2       2
```

Where `R1` is ranking of loan for each contract_id group and `R2` is ranking of each collateral under the cotnract_id. What is needed is

```
C_ID I_ID Loan R1 Prot_id Prot_value R2 maxRank PreAllocation Allocation PostAllocation Residual
1     A    c  341  1      p1        506  1       3           341        341              0      165
2     A    c  341  1      p2        366  2       3             0          0              0      366
3     A    c  341  1      p3        263  3       3             0          0              0      263
4     A    a  689  2      p1        506  1       3           689        165            524        0
5     A    a  689  2      p2        366  2       3           524        366            158        0
6     A    a  689  2      p3        263  3       3           158        158              0      105
7     A    d  720  3      p1        506  1       3           720          0            720        0
8     A    d  720  3      p2        366  2       3           720          0            720        0
9     A    d  720  3      p3        263  3       3           720        105            615        0
10    A    b  334  4      p1        506  1       3           334          0            334        0
11    A    b  334  4      p2        366  2       3           334          0            334        0
12    A    b  334  4      p3        263  3       3           334          0            334        0
13    A    e  752  5      p1        506  1       3           752          0            752        0
14    A    e  752  5      p2        366  2       3           752          0            752        0
15    A    e  752  5      p3        263  3       3           752          0            752        0
16    B    h  193  1      p5        529  1       2           193        193              0      336
17    B    h  193  1      p4        414  2       2             0          0              0      414
18    B    g  494  2      p5        529  1       2           494        336            158        0
19    B    g  494  2      p4        414  2       2           158        158              0      256
20    B    f  227  3      p5        529  1       2           227          0            227        0
21    B    f  227  3      p4        414  2       2           227        227              0       29
22    B    j  785  4      p5        529  1       2           785          0            785        0
23    B    j  785  4      p4        414  2       2           785         29            756        0
24    B    i  371  5      p5        529  1       2           371          0            371        0
25    B    i  371  5      p4        414  2       2           371          0            371        0
26    B    k  395  6      p5        529  1       2           395          0            395        0
27    B    k  395  6      p4        414  2       2           395          0            395        0
```

Only the `Allocation` column is important and the other column are just to arrive at `Allocation` column. I was able to arrive at this using loop as below

```
df3 <- as.data.frame(df3)
df3$PreAllocation <- 0
df3$Allocation <- 0
df3$PostAllocation <- 0
df3$Residual <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(df3)){
    df3$PreAllocation[i] <- ifelse(df3$R2[i]==1,df3$Loan[i],df3$PostAllocation[i-1])
    df3$Allocation[i]<- ifelse(df3$R1[i] >1, min(df3$Residual[i - 
    df3$maxRank[i]],df3$PreAllocation[i]),min(df3$PreAllocation[i],df3$Prot_value[i]))
    df3$PostAllocation[i]<- df3$PreAllocation[i] - df3$Allocation[i]
    df3$Residual[i] <- ifelse(df3$R1[i]==1, (df3$Prot_value[i] - df3$Allocation[i]), (df3$Residual[i-  
    df3$maxRank[i]] - df3$Allocation[i]))
}
```

However when dataset is big, there are performance issues. I have been trying to arrive at the same using apply functions; rowwise + transform etc but could not arrive at it. for 
1. Columns are interdependent.
2. Need to use dynamic (based on maxRank) lag of columns being generated in calculation of later rows etc.

Any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a loop was used so you could look at the value in the previous row.  Below is a solution using dplyr, which has a function `lag()` (and `lead()`) which let you look at previous (or successive) rows. It is also using `pmin()` (there's also a `pmax()`), which takes the min/max between corresponding elements in a set of vectors.

```r
# `mutate()` takes data and one or more LHS=RHS statements about the data.
# Each column in the LHS is created (or overwritten) with the logic on the
# RHS. Conveniently, we don't have to prepend each with `df$3`. 
# Uses dplyr's if_else()` instead of base R.
# `lag(x, n=1)` looks at previous row's value for x.
# Run `pmin(1:5, 5:1)` for a simple example
# of how it works.
df3 <- mutate(df3, 
              PreAllocation = if_else(R2 == 1, Loan, lag(PostAllocation, n = 1)),
              Allocation = if_else(R3 > 1, pmin(lag(Residual, n = maxRank), PreAllocation),
              pmin(PreAllocation, Prot_value)),
              PostAllocation = PreAllocation - Allocation,
              Residual = if_else(R1 == 1, Prot_value - Allocation, lag(Residual, n = maxRank - Allocation))
              )
```

I encourage you to look at the [dplyr CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) and the "Introduction to dplyr" vignette for further information.

If you'd like a syntax which is closer to base R's for subsetting & assignment, you might also consider the [data.table package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

These are very popular frameworks for data manipulation and aggregation.

Comment: Thanks smingerson. But there are two issues.  1. in taking lag we have to pass 'n' as integer and 2. reading values from column (cell) just modified can't be used in next column.

Comment: Calls in mutate happen sequentially, so preallocation exists when the second piece is called. It was helpful to include the expected output, but could edit the input so it is provided through dput for easier use by answerers? As for the dynamic lag, you are right, that is a problem. I will rethink my answer.

Comment: @ShambhuShankar I am looking to fix my example for the desired behavior. It is unclear to me, do you want to have the statements grouped by C_ID?

Comment: logic is like this. 1. Under 1 contract_id (c_id) there can be multiple loan and multiple protection_id (prot_id) and whose value is prot_value. Protection value is like collateral. It has cover the loan with largest prot_value to be used first. Yes, it needs to be grouped by contract_id (c_id). Please note that in the above data shown the column names have been moved by 1 place to the left.